# How does one extract each folder name from a path?

Tags: c#, string

My path is `\\server\folderName1\another name\something\another folder\`

How do I extract each folder name into a string if I don't know how many folders there are in the path and I don't know the folder names?

Many thanks

Answer (score 126):

```
string mypath = @"..\folder1\folder2\folder2";
string[] directories = mypath.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
```

Edit:
This returns each individual folder in the directories array.  You can get the number of folders returned like this:

```
int folderCount = directories.Length;
```

Comment: I added a small enhancement (somewhere at this post), but I marked this as correct as well.  Well played!

Comment: Please note that there is a [Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.altdirectoryseparatorchar.aspx) which might have to be handled as well. (e.g. via `mypath.Split(new[] { Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar });`)

Comment: This is completely wrecked on a path like `\\ticows01\c$\AgArmourFTP`. Sorry, but approach is too simplistic.

Answer (score 35):

This is good in the general case:

```
yourPath.Split(@"\/", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

There is no empty element in the returned array if the path itself ends in a (back)slash (e.g. "\foo\bar\"). However, you will have to be sure that `yourPath` is really a directory and not a file. You can find out what it is and compensate if it is a file like this:

```
if(Directory.Exists(yourPath)) {
  var entries = yourPath.Split(@"\/", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
}
else if(File.Exists(yourPath)) {
  var entries = Path.GetDirectoryName(yourPath).Split(
                    @"\/", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
}
else {
  // error handling
}
```

I believe this covers all bases without being too pedantic. It will return a `string[]` that you can iterate over with `foreach` to get each directory in turn.

If you want to use constants instead of the `@"\/"` magic string, you need to use

```
var separators = new char[] {
  Path.DirectorySeparatorChar,  
  Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar  
};
```

and then use `separators` instead of `@"\/"` in the code above. Personally, I find this too verbose and would most likely not do it.

Comment: This does not appear to work in C# 6 with the following errors:
`path.Split(@"\/", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
(1,12): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'char'
(1,19): error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.StringSplitOptions' to 'char'`. Creating a new char[] with the splitter in it does work:
`path.Split(new char[] { Path.DirectorySeparatorChar }, options: StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);` does work.

Answer (score 11):

I see your [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401304/c-sharp-how-do-i-extract-each-folder-name-from-a-path#answer-9647836) [Wolf5370](https://stackoverflow.com/users/378526/wolf5370) and raise you.

```
internal static List<DirectoryInfo> Split(this DirectoryInfo path)
{
    if(path == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("path");
    var ret = new List<DirectoryInfo>();
    if (path.Parent != null) ret.AddRange(Split(path.Parent));
    ret.Add(path);
    return ret;
}
```

On the path `c:\folder1\folder2\folder3` this returns

`c:\`

`c:\folder1`

`c:\folder1\folder2`

`c:\folder1\folder2\folder3`

In that order

#### OR

```
internal static List<string> Split(this DirectoryInfo path)
{
    if(path == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("path");
    var ret = new List<string>();
    if (path.Parent != null) ret.AddRange(Split(path.Parent));
    ret.Add(path.Name);
    return ret;
}
```

will return

`c:\`

`folder1`

`folder2`

`folder3`

Comment: That works pretty well for absolute paths, but not so great if you have a relative path and you want the output to reflect that.

Answer (score 10):

Realise this is an old post, but I came across it looking - in the end I decided apon the below function as it sorted what I was doing at the time better than any of the above:

```
private static List<DirectoryInfo> SplitDirectory(DirectoryInfo parent)
{
    if (parent == null) return null;
    var rtn = new List<DirectoryInfo>();
    var di = parent;

    while (di.Name != di.Root.Name)
    {
    rtn.Add(di);
    di = di.Parent;
    }
    rtn.Add(di.Root);

    rtn.Reverse();
    return rtn;
}
```

Comment: `rtn.Add(new DirectoryInfo(di));` is wrong, should be `rtn.Add(di);` and also change `rtn.Add(new DirectoryInfo(di.Root));` for `rtn.Add(di.Root);`

Comment: Thanks for this example. Storing DirectoryInfo objects instead of simple strings is useful if you need to interact with the folders later on.

Comment: I implemented a more concise method below inspired by your answer.

Answer (score 6):

There are a few ways that a file path can be represented. You should use the `System.IO.Path` class to get the separators for the OS, since it can vary between UNIX and Windows. Also, most (or all if I'm not mistaken) .NET libraries accept either a '\' or a '/' as a path separator, regardless of OS. For this reason, I'd use the Path class to split your paths. Try something like the following:

```
string originalPath = "\\server\\folderName1\\another\ name\\something\\another folder\\";
string[] filesArray = originalPath.Split(Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar,
                              Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
```

This should work regardless of the number of folders or the names.

Answer (score 5):

```
public static IEnumerable<string> Split(this DirectoryInfo path)
{
    if (path == null) 
        throw new ArgumentNullException("path");
    if (path.Parent != null)
        foreach(var d in Split(path.Parent))
            yield return d;
    yield return path.Name;
}
```

Comment: I like your approach, but I made an implementation that is simpler, without recursion. +1

Answer (score 5):

Inspired by the earlier answers, but simpler, and without recursion. Also, it does not care what the separation symbol is, as `Dir.Parent` covers this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Split a directory in its components.
    /// Input e.g: a/b/c/d.
    /// Output: d, c, b, a.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Dir"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static IEnumerable<string> DirectorySplit(this DirectoryInfo Dir)
    {
        while (Dir != null)
        {
            yield return Dir.Name;
            Dir = Dir.Parent;
        }
    }
```

Either stick this in a `static` class to create a nice extension method, or just leave out the `this` (and `static`).

Usage example (as an extension method) to access the path parts by number:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Return one part of the directory path.
    /// Path e.g.: a/b/c/d. PartNr=0 is a, Nr 2 = c.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Dir"></param>
    /// <param name="PartNr"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string DirectoryPart(this DirectoryInfo Dir, int PartNr)
    {
        string[] Parts = Dir.DirectorySplit().ToArray();
        int L = Parts.Length;
        return PartNr >= 0 && PartNr < L ? Parts[L - 1 - PartNr] : "";
    }
```

Both above methods are now in my personal library, hence the xml comments. Usage example:

```
    DirectoryInfo DI_Data = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\Hunter\Data\2019\w38\abc\000.d");
    label_Year.Text = DI_Data.DirectoryPart(3); // --> 2019
    label_Entry.Text = DI_Data.DirectoryPart(6);// --> 000.d
```

Answer (score 4):

```
    // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
    /// <summary>
    /// Use to emulate the C lib function _splitpath()
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="path">The path to split</param>
    /// <param name="rootpath">optional root if a relative path</param>
    /// <returns>the folders in the path. 
    ///     Item 0 is drive letter with ':' 
    ///     If path is UNC path then item 0 is "\\"
    /// </returns>
    /// <example>
    /// string p1 = @"c:\p1\p2\p3\p4";
    /// string[] ap1 = p1.SplitPath();
    /// // ap1 = {"c:", "p1", "p2", "p3", "p4"}
    /// string p2 = @"\\server\p2\p3\p4";
    /// string[] ap2 = p2.SplitPath();
    /// // ap2 = {@"\\", "server", "p2", "p3", "p4"}
    /// string p3 = @"..\p3\p4";
    /// string root3 = @"c:\p1\p2\";
    /// string[] ap3 = p1.SplitPath(root3);
    /// // ap3 = {"c:", "p1", "p3", "p4"}
    /// </example>
    public static string[] SplitPath(this string path, string rootpath = "")
    {
        string drive;
        string[] astr;
        path = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(rootpath, path));
        if (path[1] == ':')
        {
            drive = path.Substring(0, 2);
            string newpath = path.Substring(2);
            astr = newpath.Split(new[] { Path.DirectorySeparatorChar }
                , StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        }
        else
        {
            drive = @"\\";
            astr = path.Split(new[] { Path.DirectorySeparatorChar }
                , StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        }
        string[] splitPath = new string[astr.Length + 1];
        splitPath[0] = drive;
        astr.CopyTo(splitPath, 1);
        return splitPath;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe call [Directory.GetParent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getparent.aspx) in a loop? That's if you want the full path to each directory and not just the directory names.

Answer (score 2):

The quick answer is to use the .Split('\\') method.

Comment: Take care if you want to put the array back together with `Path.Combine` if you had the drive letter at the beginning of the path - this will go back together as `c:server\folderName1...`.

Answer (score 1):

I use this for looping folder ftp server

```
public List<string> CreateMultiDirectory(string remoteFile)
      
var separators = new char[] { Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar };
string[] directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(remoteFile).Split(separators);

var path = new List<string>();
var folder = string.Empty;
foreach (var item in directory)
{
     folder += $@"{item}\";
     path.Add(folder);
}

return path;
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you need to do something with each folder, have a look at the System.IO.DirectoryInfo class. It also has a Parent property that allows you to navigate to the parent directory.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the following method which works for me.

```
protected bool isDirectoryFound(string path, string pattern)
    {
        bool success = false;

        DirectoryInfo directories = new DirectoryInfo(@path);
        DirectoryInfo[] folderList = directories.GetDirectories();

        Regex rx = new Regex(pattern);

        foreach (DirectoryInfo di in folderList)
        {
            if (rx.IsMatch(di.Name))
            {
                success = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        return success;
    }
```

The lines most pertinent to your question being:

DirectoryInfo directories = new DirectoryInfo(@path);
DirectoryInfo[] folderList = directories.GetDirectories();

Answer (score 0):

```
DirectoryInfo objDir = new DirectoryInfo(direcotryPath);
DirectoryInfo [] directoryNames =  objDir.GetDirectories("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

This will give you all the directories and subdirectories.

Comment: If they exist, that is.

Answer (score 0):

I am adding to Matt Brunell's answer.

```
            string[] directories = myStringWithLotsOfFolders.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);

            string previousEntry = string.Empty;
            if (null != directories)
            {
                foreach (string direc in directories)
                {
                    string newEntry = previousEntry + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + direc;
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(newEntry))
                    {
                        if (!newEntry.Equals(Convert.ToString(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(newEntry);
                            previousEntry = newEntry;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

This should give you:

"\server"

"\server\folderName1"

"\server\folderName1\another name"

"\server\folderName1\another name\something"

"\server\folderName1\another name\something\another folder\"

(or sort your resulting collection by the string.Length of each value.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a modification of Wolf's answer that leaves out the root and fixes what seemed to be a couple of bugs. I used it to generate a breadcrumbs and I didn't want the root showing.

this is an extension of the `DirectoryInfo` type.

```cs
public static List<DirectoryInfo> PathParts(this DirectoryInfo source, string rootPath)
{
  if (source == null) return null;
  DirectoryInfo root = new DirectoryInfo(rootPath);
  var pathParts = new List<DirectoryInfo>();
  var di = source;

  while (di != null && di.FullName != root.FullName)
  {
    pathParts.Add(di);
    di = di.Parent;
  }

  pathParts.Reverse();
  return pathParts;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just coded this since I didn't find any already built in in C#.

```
/// <summary>
/// get the directory path segments.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="directoryPath">the directory path.</param>
/// <returns>a IEnumerable<string> containing the get directory path segments.</returns>
public IEnumerable<string> GetDirectoryPathSegments(string directoryPath)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(directoryPath))
    { throw new Exception($"Invalid Directory: {directoryPath ?? "null"}"); }

    var currentNode = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(directoryPath);

    var targetRootNode = currentNode.Root;
    if (targetRootNode == null) return new string[] { currentNode.Name };
    var directorySegments = new List<string>();
    while (string.Compare(targetRootNode.FullName, currentNode.FullName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) != 0)
    {
        directorySegments.Insert(0, currentNode.Name);
        currentNode = currentNode.Parent;
    }
    directorySegments.Insert(0, currentNode.Name);
    return directorySegments;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to contribute using this options (without split method)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace SampleConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var filePaths = new[]
            {
                "C:/a/b/c/d/files-samples/formdata.bmp",
                @"\\127.0.0.1\c$\a\b\c\d\formdata.bmp",
                "/usr/home/john/a/b/c/d/formdata.bmp"
            };

            foreach (var filePath in filePaths)
            {

                var directorySegments = GetDirectorySegments(filePath);
                Console.WriteLine(filePath);
                Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine,
                    directorySegments.Select((e, i) => $"\t Segment#={i + 1} Text={e}")));
            }

        }

        private static IList<string> GetDirectorySegments(string filePath)
        {
            var directorySegments = new List<string>();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath))
                return directorySegments;

            var fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
            if (fileInfo.Directory == null) 
                return directorySegments;

            for (var currentDirectory = fileInfo.Directory;
                currentDirectory != null;
                currentDirectory = currentDirectory.Parent)
                directorySegments.Insert(0, currentDirectory.Name);

            return directorySegments;
        }
    }
}
```

if everything goes well, an output will be like:

```
C:/a/b/c/d/files-samples/formdata.bmp
         Segment#=1 Text=C:\
         Segment#=2 Text=a
         Segment#=3 Text=b
         Segment#=4 Text=c
         Segment#=5 Text=d
         Segment#=6 Text=files-samples
\\127.0.0.1\c$\a\b\c\d\formdata.bmp
         Segment#=1 Text=\\127.0.0.1\c$
         Segment#=2 Text=a
         Segment#=3 Text=b
         Segment#=4 Text=c
         Segment#=5 Text=d
/usr/home/john/a/b/c/d/formdata.bmp
         Segment#=1 Text=C:\
         Segment#=2 Text=usr
         Segment#=3 Text=home
         Segment#=4 Text=john
         Segment#=5 Text=a
         Segment#=6 Text=b
         Segment#=7 Text=c
         Segment#=8 Text=d
```

You can still perform additional filters to GetDirectorySegments (since you have an instance of DirectoryInfo you can check atributes or use the Exist property)