# Getting Folder Name(s) from Path

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

If I have a file path like "C:\My Documents\Images\Image1.png", how can I get the parent folder name of the "Image1.png" file? In this case, "Images", but that's just a sample. I've looked through `System.IO.Path` and there doesn't seem to be anything there. Maybe I'm overlooking it, but I have no idea where it would be.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Like this:

```
Path.GetFileName(Path.GetDirectoryName(something))
```

Comment: Snazzy, I didn't know you could tackle the problem like this. +1

Comment: Great, this is the most straightforward. Thanx!

Answer (score 5):

Use `System.IO.FileInfo`.

```
string fl = "C:\My Documents\Images\Image1.png";
System.IO.FileInfo fi = new System.IO.FileInfo(fl);
string owningDirectory = fi.Directory.Name;
```

Comment: This property returns the full path to the directory, which is not what he wants.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out - updated.  FileInfo.Directory.Name will return the desired result.

Answer (score 4):

Create an instance of

```
 System.IO.FileInfo f1 = new FileInfo("filepath");
                    DirectoryInfo dir=f1.Directory;
                    string dirName = dir.Name;
                    string fullDirPath = dir.FullName;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var directoryFullPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(@"C:\My Documents\Images\Image1.png");
var directoryName = Path.GetFileName(directoryFullPath);  \\ Images
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this answer; [C# How do I extract each folder name from a path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401304/c-how-do-i-extract-each-folder-name-from-a-path) and then just go for the last element in the array.

Answer (score 1):

The following method will extract all the directory names and file name

```
Dim path As String = "C:\My Documents\Images\Image1.png"
Dim list As String() = path.Split("\")
Console.WriteLine(list.ElementAt(list.Count - 2))
```

Comment: well, the title hints at the possibility of getting multiple folder names - wasn't sure if the asker may have wanted more than just the one parent directory, so why not?

Comment: You should also split on the alternate path separator (/ for Windows)