# C# get directory name

Tags: c#

I have a folder in `c:\program files(x86)\company\application\` which contains all the app files.

How can I get the path like `C:\program files(x86)\company`?

I cannot use `Application.Startuppath` as it will return `c:\program files)x86)\company\application`.

Thanks.

Comment: Does "c:\program files)x86)\company\application\..\" work for you?

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401304/c-sharp-how-do-i-extract-each-folder-name-from-a-path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Directory.GetParent(string path)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getparent)

In your app include `System.IO` namespace

```
using System.IO;
```

and use

```
string desired_path = Directory.GetParent(Application.StartupPath);
                       // will return c:\program files(x86)\company
        // because app path will have c:\program files(x86)\company\application\
```

Answer (score 0):

See This MSDN Content about [`System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx)

So, Include :

```
using System.IO;
```

Now Your Code:

```
string ApplicationPath = Application.StartupPath;
string YourPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(ApplicationPath);
// This will get "C:\program files(x86)\company" from "C:\program files(x86)\company\application"
```

Answer (score 0):

Best to use `Environment.CurrentDirectory` and it will help you.

Please refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.currentdirectory%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

for more details.