# REGEX to stop directory traversal

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I am trying to create a Regular Expression for validation to stop directory traversal attacks. I want the user to be able to specify anything within the C:\temp directory. So the below is fine

```
c:\temp\hello\world.txt
```

but obviously, the directory below would be unacceptable.

```
c:\temp\..\Windows\world.txt
```

My issue is that I am unsure how I can allow one period (.) but not two in a row. I need one obviously for extensions i.e. (world.txt) but can not have two. This is what I have so far:

```
^([c]:\\)\\?(temp)([^(\.\.)]){0,200}$
```

So I am trying to say not two periods [^\.\.] and the \\? part is because it accepts escaped directories as well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What makes you think regex is the right tool here?

Comment: I am not too sure how else to go about validating a directory. It is an aspx application with C# codebehind. I am open to a better way if there is one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401304/how-does-one-extract-each-folder-name-from-a-path

Comment: This is not a new problem.  It is highly likely that there is existing code that has been written, tested and debugged that solves your problem for you.  Find that code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try with this:

```
^(c:\\)\\?(temp)(?!.*\.\.).{0,200}$
```

Here I have modified your regex a bit to ensure that there is no consecutive dots.

1. `(?!.*\.\.)` This negative look ahead starts scanning right
   after `c:\temp` part is found. Itd will scan till the end of string and if it returns true (which means no consecutive dots) then the following part takes action.
2. `.{0,200}` the dot here matches any character from 0 to 200 times

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1sSILB/1)

Comment: Thanks, to all who replied, I am looking at alternative methods, but have marked Rizwan's answer as correct... as it was the only actual answer and the regular expression works :).