# How to exclude sub directories based on array values

Tags: c#

I need to get the full path from directories but use an array to exclude certain paths without entering the full path into the array.

I am getting the path of directories like this:

```
List<string> dirs = di.GetDirectories("vault*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
.Select(x => x.FullName).ToList();
```

The directory looks like this: I need to filter based on the parent after C.

```
C:\A\vault
C:\B\vault
C:\C\vault
```

I have an array like this:

```
string[] exclude = new string[] {"A", "B"};
```

Doing something like below does not work because it will require I enter the full name of the path to exclude in the array, which can get nasty:

```
dirs.Except(exclude);
```

How can I do this better so that I can easily update the array without all the extraneous characters of longer paths? Example: Adding an additional path in the future to exclude.

Comment: Do you want to exclude all path which contain A or B (in your example), would `.contain` not work?

Comment: I have updated the question to show the structure of the directory.

Comment: regex might be the most general approach, but if in your case the exclude directory is always after the root (c:\) then you can build a string using root + values from array and again use contain.

Comment: You can also implement your own like operator which works similar to the SQL like operator...can see once similar implementation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374481/like-operator-in-linq

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does one extract each folder name from a path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401304/how-does-one-extract-each-folder-name-from-a-path)

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work just fine:

```
string[] exclude = new string[] { "A", "B" };

List<string> dirs =
    di
        .GetDirectories("vault*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        .Where(x => !exclude.Contains(x.Name))
        .Select(x => x.FullName)
        .ToList();
```

I've tested it. *Note that the `Contains` being used is against `exclude` - so this is checking whether the `Name` exists within the array, it is not doing some form of substring search.*

---

To be a little more robust it might be worth using this:

```
.Where(x => !exclude.Select(y => y.ToUpperInvariant()).Contains(x.Name.ToUpperInvariant()))
```

Comment: For this set of data, yes. What if one of the excluded strings was `a`? that would exclude all directories.

Comment: @ZoharPeled - Why is that?

Comment: @ZoharPeled  You check on the `Name` property of `DirectoryInfo`. It only contains the exact name of that folder and not the full path.

Answer (score 0):

You have to changed `SearchPattern` something like:

```
 List<string> dirs = di.GetDirectories("C\\Vault*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
           .Select(x => x.FullName).ToList();
```

All `A and B` are excluded already

Comment: Wouldn't that exclude `C` as well?

Comment: No C is not excluded according to your `string[] exclude = new string[] {"A", "B"};
`

Comment: No, you are correct, `C` would not be excluded (not my question, though). However, what if there was a path `C:\D\Vault`? that would be excluded, wouldn't it?