# Check directory structure

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to check whether a directory is in a format of

Ex:

This should be valid:
D:\TESTDIR\FOLDER1\FOLDER2\Somerandomfiles

This is not valid:
D:\TESTDIR\FOLDER1\Somerandomfiles

Basically I need to make sure that for every folder there should be a subfolder inside. note that a single folder may contain multiple subfolder. Then the subfolder will contain the files such as text files/pdf files etc.

```
   //not sure how/where to place to check if folder has a subfolder 
   var _dir = Directory.GetDirectories(@"D:\TESTDIR");

   foreach(var _folder1 in _dir)
   {
       // check if contains folder2? if not 
       // MessageBox.Show(folder1name);
       var _folder2 = Directory.GetDirectories(_folder1);
            
       foreach (var _path in _folder2)
       {
           // do something
       }
   }
```

Comment: If it were me, I would add the search option to not get subdirectories. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getdirectories?view=net-5.0#System_IO_Directory_GetDirectories_System_String_System_String_System_IO_SearchOption_  . You could then know what level each folder is at more easily. You might also consider splitting the path string on the directory separator. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401304/how-does-one-extract-each-folder-name-from-a-path

Comment: I mean not get subdirectories from Directory.GetDirectories

Comment: I suspect it's because you're not overly clear. Could you express "note that folder2 may be multiple in 1 folder1" more clearly?

Comment: meaning that inside folder1 may contains many subfolders (folder2) should have have mentioned subfolders instead

Comment: edited hopefully its clear/better thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it right, I just modified your code a little:

```
var dir = Directory.GetDirectories(@"D:\TESTDIR");

foreach(var folder1 in dir)
{
    var folder2 = Directory.GetDirectories(folder1);
    // If no directories are found in that subfolder, skip it.
    // Basically it would work the same without if, as loop
    // would not run even one iteration, but it's more readable.
    if(folder2.Count == 0) continue;
    
    foreach (var path in folder2)
    {
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(path);
        // Same as above, check if there are any files.
        if(files.Count == 0) break;
        // Do some work
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for this! will try this one as it is readable for me o;

Comment: marking this as answer! guess I'm overthinking and didn't realize Count() thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would start this:

```
var query =
    from dir in Directory.GetDirectories(@"D:\TESTDIR")
    select new
    {
        dir,
        valid =
            Directory.GetDirectories(dir).Any()
            && Directory.GetDirectories(dir).All(child => Directory.GetFiles(child).Any())
    };
```

That's going to check each of the directories in `@"D:\TESTDIR"` and ensure each has at least one subfolder and that each subfolder has at least one file.