# Get folder name of selectedpath in folderBrowserDialog

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi how can I display selected folder name in textbox. I have 3 Folder. It display the 2 folders in the textbox but the other one it won't display.

For example:

> C:\EmpRecord\Details\Name\MiddleName\Lastname

The 2 folder name display without a problem.

For the Middlename here's the code:

```
middleName.Text = Path.GetFileName(Path.GetDirectoryName(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath));
```

Lastname:

```
lastName.Text = new DirectoryInfo(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath).Name;
```

For the **Name** it doesn't display in the textbox. How can I display it in textbox?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401304/how-does-one-extract-each-folder-name-from-a-path) answer your incomprehensible question ?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call `GetFileName` and `GetDirectoryName` multiple times, e.g.

```cs
var folderPath = @"C:\EmpRecord\Details\Name\MiddleName\Lastname";

Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFileName(folderPath);

folderPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(folderPath);

Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFileName(folderPath);

folderPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(folderPath);

Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFileName(folderPath);
```

That will display the following:

```
Lastname
MiddleName
Name
```

Comment: How to implement for textbox?

Comment: @TintinSantos, you're seriously asking me how to display a `string` in a `TextBox`? Apart from that, you're already displaying the result of `Path.GetFileName` in a `TextBox` in your own code so why do I need to show you how to do something that you're already doing?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Name.Text = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath.Substring(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath.LastIndexOf(@"\") + 1).Substring(4));
```

Comment: I tried this but it does not work

Comment: Does you code make sure that a folder is selected?

Comment: Yes the folder is selected. it display MiddleName not the Name

Comment: No, don't try that. Always use the `Path` class to manipulate file and folder paths unless you have a specific reason not to. No such reason exists in this case.

Comment: It tried but it only remove the letters. For example Name -> me

Answer (score 0):

Another one using the [Uri](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri?view=netframework-4.6.1&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Uri)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%253Dv4.6.1)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue) class:

```
Uri uri = new Uri(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);            
if (uri.Segments.Length >= 3)
{
    lastName.Text = uri.Segments[uri.Segments.Length - 1].Trim('/');
    middleName.Text = uri.Segments[uri.Segments.Length - 2].Trim('/');
    firstName.Text = uri.Segments[uri.Segments.Length - 3].Trim('/');
}
```